# Xubuntu - Help optimize display ro visually impaired

Tags: xubuntu, display

Xubuntu 18.04

I am setting up Xubuntu on the machine for a non-technical older person with visual impairment.

So far I have managed to increase only Font and Icon sizes, but is there an easy way, or package we can download, to make global size adjustments without having to use the terminal?

Comment: I don't use Xubuntu (but Bionic Beaver 18.04). In settings do you have an option Universal Settings?

Comment: I use Xubuntu (Xfce4) but I am not aware of any global settings.  However, you are on the right path of setting the Icon and Font sizes.  You can also do the Accessibility with Assistive Technologies, etc.  https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/accessibility  Also, looking in the Settings -> Appearance you can try setting a Style to High Contrast or something that might be easier to see.  Also, right-clicking the desktop and choosing Desktop Settings is the best place to set the Icon and Font size as they are under the Icons tab.